# Why do some voltage reference ICs (LM385B) have 8 pin packages where 6 pins are NC?

Tags: packages, voltage-reference

A search for voltage reference LM385B reveals that most of its many versions come in either 3-pin TO packages or 8-pin SOIC/TSSOP packages. Very few are 3-pin SOT-23 packages. I was wondering why is this? Why have 8 pin packages where 6 pins are NC?

Comment: Some devices have a larger die size.

Comment: If the silicon die size is too large to fit insize the die cavity of a SOT23 package, then the larger 8SOIC package would be needed.

Comment: Hmm I haven't come accross 2 pin regulators yet. Are they just fancy zener diodes? I wonder why a normal zener wouldn't suit the job.

Comment: @Bradman175 -- they're used the same way as Zeners, yes, but provide better performance than a Zener (i.e. more accurate and stable over temperature and time)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Seems as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple issues at play here, actually.  Die size, as mentioned, is one of them -- a SO-8 or even a TSSOP-8 can accommodate a larger die than a SOT-23 can, although modern references *are* available in SOT-23 packages these days (the Intersil FGA parts come to mind, specifically).

Other reasons include mechanical stability for high-accuracy references and the need to provide post-packaging trim access due to packaging process induced shifts in the reference voltage.  [LTC AN82](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an82f.pdf) discusses these problems in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Std Packages are selected for automation, so another tool adapter does not have to be purchased.

8-DIP, TO-92, SOIC and TSSOP are avail

The TO-92 has 3 leads like small signal transistors

Comment: What makes SOT-23 not a standard package, in this context?